# Integers (strictly) between 0 and 1 form the basis of transcendental number theory?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

In a [MathOverflow comment](https://mathoverflow.net/a/182010/38176) on the [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182006/38176) of "What is the most useful non-existing object of your field?", an answer is given

> A number which is less than 1 and greater than 1.

Which elicited a highly upvoted reply

> Integers (strictly) between 0 and 1 form the basis of transcendental number theory.

What does this mean? Is there a different, more relaxed, definition of an integer used for transcendental number theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many proofs in transcendental number theory reach a contradiction by coming up with a quantity which on the one hand is a positive integer, and on the other hand is less than one.

A particular simple example is the proof that $e$ is irrational. Suppose $e = p/q$. Then for $r \geq q$,
$$r!e = \sum_{n \leq r} \frac{r!}{n!} + \frac{1}{r+1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{r+2} + \frac{1}{(r+2)(r+3)} + \cdots \right).$$
Now consider the quantity
$$ \frac{1}{r+1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{r+2} + \frac{1}{(r+2)(r+3)} + \cdots \right). $$
On the one hand, it's a positive integer. On the other, as $r\to\infty$ it tends to 0.

In other proofs we might come up with (the analog of) some explicit $r$ for which the quantity is less than $1$, rather than showing that it tends to $0$.